# conda run -n Linienerkennung python Linienerkennung.py fails, because it does not use the environment(Linienerkennung)

Tags: anaconda, conda

I want to run python code via this command:

```
conda run -n Linienerkennung python Linienerkennung.py
```

But conda tries to execute the script without the environment(Linienerkennung) and so I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

If I run this command:

```
python3 Linienerkennung.py
```

Python uses the active conda environment and the script works well.

I tried to use

```
conda run -n Linienerkennung python3 Linienerkennung.py
```

but the result was the same.
I created a new environment, but it did not work too.

Versions:

- OS: Pop!_os 19.10
- conda version: 4.8.1
- python3 version: 3.7.5

Have someone an idea why conda do not uses the packages of the definied environment?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
conda run -n Linienerkennung C:\<YourCondaInstallFolder>\envs\Linienerkennung\python.exe -c Linienerkennung.py
```

(Maybe the '-c' is not needed).
Now, you specifically call the python instance of your active environment.

That said ... I am having problems with Conda Run too ....